# XAMPP installed but local host is not responding

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP and running Apache and MySQL on it. When I go to test it with http://localhost , I just get a blank page and the XAMPP page does not load.

here is a screen shot of my XAMPP window
[image]

Comment: Apache needs port 80 to run , check which program using port 80 , most probably Skype exit it and restart xampp

Comment: According to that screenshot: try `http://localhost:8080/` - you have some other service using port 80 so `apache (httpd)` has been assigned port 8080.

Comment: I tried http://localhost:8080/ and it worked.

Comment: I see the xampp page, but I do not see the option for creating a database.